Replaced door lock/sensor on Samsung washing machine, now the breaker trips whenever I plug it in
Model WH456100A. The door latch broke so I replaced the part and now I can't even plug it in. Had no issues before this. Please help!

You goofed up something, like most of us do from time to time.  Possibility you have a ground touching hot/hot touching ground(housing).  Turn off the breaker/unplug it, and redo the job, maybe adding electric tape here or there.

I'm not sure what I could have done though. It was a simple process of just unplugging the old sensor and plugging the new one in.

Sometimes the simple stuff can be difficult.  I have turned off a breaker to change a switch.  Found out soon it was the wrong breaker when sparks flew.

You may have bumped something else, or pinched a wire when reassembling and broken insulation... Open it up again and inspect everything in the area. If it isn't obvious by inspection, you're looking at getting the circuit diagram and a multimeter and testing what is and isn't connected until you find the problem.

plug it the other way

@BrokenWasher -- is this breaker a regular breaker, a GFCI, or an AFCI?
